# How to share object reference from one uwp application to another using shared memory?

Tags: c#, uwp, ipc, shared-memory

I was trying to make communications between UWP Client App and a background Service (out-of-process).

1. ClientApp ((Universal Windows) C#) ServiceApp (Windows Runtime
2. ServiceApp (Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows)) => This is the background service

Communication has been established using app service. When I was trying to send an object from the client app to the service app, it was getting NULL in the service app.

*Note: Both-sided communication needs to be established here. If an object property is changed from client app side, I want to get that from service app side. If a modification is done from service app side, I need to get that from client app side.*

Now I've 2 questions.

1. How can I share object reference between these 2 apps using shared
   memory?
2. Is it possible to share object reference using "ValueSet"?

I wasn't able to find any good resources with any sample code. It would be very helpful if someone could share detailed solution.

Thanks

Comment: AppService can use “ValueSet” share object. However, it seems to there are some errors in your communication process. I suggest you could check the connection status. For more troubleshooting methods, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service).

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no such API about “shared memory” to share object between two apps in uwp, which is not feasible.

For sharing data between two apps, Uwp provides some classes under the [Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-20348) namespace to do this. There are two important class are [DataTransferManager class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager?view=winrt-20348) and [DataPackage class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackage?view=winrt-20348), DataTransferManager is use to initiate a share operation, and the DataPackage class is use to package the content.

You could use [GetForCurrentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager.getforcurrentview?view=winrt-20348#Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_DataTransferManager_GetForCurrentView) method to get a DataTransferManager object. Then you need to add an event listener for the [datarequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager.datarequested?view=winrt-20348) event to the object. When a sharing operation starts, this event will be triggered. Besides, the source app need to put the data being shared in a DataPackage object and sends that object to the target app for processing.

Please refer to [Sharing content source app sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/ShareSource) to know the detailed source app code, since this process involves two app, you also need to install and deploy the [Sharing content target app sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/?redirectedfrom=MSDN-samples) .

Comment: Actually, there is a Nuget package System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles. So, technically, it is possible to use shared memory in UWP, but this would be much harder way than what Arya proposed.

Comment: Hello @Arya Ding,
How will the source app send the object to the target app?
Let's assume, I set a text from source app (using request.Data.SetText("Hello world!")). Now I want to send it to target app, how can it be done? Can you please tell the communication procedure?

Comment: @Arya Ding
The sample project you've mentioned, it uses "Share Contract" to select the target app.
In my case, ServiceApp doesn't have any UI, it's a background app. My target is to send data (Class object, properties etc) from ClientApp to ServiceApp, process the data in background, then send it back to the ClientApp.
How can I use "Share Contract" in here to exchange data?

Comment: That is only an element in xaml page, you could refer to the code behind to implement the function to get target app information.