# Shared memory or reference to memory objects for UWP multi instance app?

Tags: uwp, shared-memory, shared-data, multi-instance-deployment

Is there any way to create shared memory between multiple instance of an UWP app?

For example, I need to load hundreds of images (as Bitmap) in one instance of UWP app.
Loading same images in the other instance can take double memory.

Is there any way that multiple instances of the UWP app will be using same memory reference? Or there is there any way to reduce this redundant memory usage?

Tried shared memory. But looks like no support for UWP.

Currently loading separately which is multiplying the memory usage.

Also, does shared data come in help in this case?

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68184999/how-to-share-object-reference-from-one-uwp-application-to-another-using-shared-m

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say that there is no API in UWP that could be used to share memory as you want.  When reading from the file from different instance of UWP apps, it will create their own memory usage.